# Yelp API Python Not Getting Any Results

Tags: python, api, yelp

I am using sample.py: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/blob/master/fusion/python/sample.py

Provided by Yelp Fusion. I have inserted my API_KEY where it is necessary and I am not sure what else I need to do to receive results. This is currently what I see when I run sample.py.

```
PS C:\Users\jacob\OneDrive\Documents\se319\yelp-fusion\fusion\python> python sample.py
Querying https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search ...
No businesses for dinner in San Francisco, CA found.
PS C:\Users\jacob\OneDrive\Documents\se319\yelp-fusion\fusion\python>
```

Here is what happens when I print the args that are in the request function:

```
PS C:\Users\jacob\OneDrive\Documents\se319\yelp-fusion\fusion\python> python sample.py
Querying https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search ...

https://api.yelp.com //this is the host

/v3/businesses/search //this is the path

(Censored API Key) //api key correctly prints out

{'term': 'dinner', 'location': 'San+Francisco,+CA', 'limit': 3} //url params

No businesses for dinner in San Francisco, CA found.
```

I added spaces in between for readability.

When I add a print option at response = search(API_KEY, term, location)

Querying https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search ...
{'error': {'code': 'TOKEN_INVALID', 'description': 'Invalid access token or authorization header.'}}
No businesses for dinner in San Francisco, CA found.

Could someone point me in the right direction to fix this issue please?

EDIT: I didn't have the full API key pasted. Rookie mistake.

Comment: Boooo screen shots are bad

Comment: Why shouldn't I use a screen shot?

Comment: It's not very helpful.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I see. I made the change. Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: Maybe. In the `request` function, add some lines to print out each arg to make sure they are what you expect, and then post the results

Comment: I posted the results.

Comment: Hm, not seeing anything obvious. Put `print(response)` right under `response = search(API_KEY, term, location)` in the `query_api` function and post results

Comment: Or get an api key that you can share, that would make things much easier

Comment: So i'm getting the same error you are, but when i dig deeper, it's showing "Token_Invalid". The sample file they provide isn't very good. And i see you are getting the same problem. So it's not the code, it's the token.

Comment: Dang. Any suggestion on what I should use instead? Trying to get a list of restaurants when given a zip code in JSON format.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do much until you get the token thing sorted out. They may have some trouble shooting tips. Worst case, I guess you could try scraping the yelp site directly instead of going through their api.